# Right to left TextFormField

Tags: dart, flutter

How to use TextFormField widget while the icon and text are placed at the right side?

I'm currently using the following code:

```
new TextFormField(
    obscureText: obscure,
    style: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
    ),
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
        icon: new Icon(
            icon,
            color: Colors.white,
        ),
        border: InputBorder.none,
        hintText: hint,
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 30.0, right: 30.0, bottom: 30.0, left: 5.0),
    ),
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add textAligin: TextAlign.end and use suffixIcon

```
 new TextFormField(
    textAlign: TextAlign.end,
    obscureText: obscure,
    style: const TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
    ),
    decoration: new InputDecoration(
        suffixIcon: new Icon(
            icon,
            color: Colors.white,
        ),
        border: InputBorder.none,
        hintText: hint,
        hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 15.0),
        contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.only(
        top: 30.0, right: 30.0, bottom: 30.0, left: 5.0),
    ),
)
```

Comment: I had already tested this. There is a problem when I use textAligin: TextAlign.end keyboard does not open.

Comment: i tried it like this and the keyboard does open... i do not know

Answer (score 0):

You can use both of `direction` and `align`:

```dart
TextFormField(
  textAlign: TextAlign.right,
  textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
```